# Python loop for removing rows of keyword data with zero revenue in revenue attribution columns

Tags: python

I used a similar loop to remove duplicates and tried altering it a bit in order to delete entire rows  that contain a value of "0" in the "lastClickRevenue" column.

The code executes without spitting out any errors, but it does not delete the rows as I had hoped. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    for i in range(len(lastClickRevenue)):
        if lastClickRevenue[i] == "0":                        
            currentRevenueKeywords.pop(i)                           
            sessions.pop(i)                                         
            sales.pop(i)                                            
            lastClickRevenue.pop(i)                                 
            firstClickRevenue.pop(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always a bad idea to iterate over a container and modify it at the same time.

Better would be to write it with a list comprehension like this:

```
lastClickRevenue = [x for x in lastClickRevenue if x != 0]
```

To handle the other ones:

```
currentRevenueKeywords = [x for x,y in zip(currentRevenueKeywords, lastClickRevenue) if y != 0]
sessions = [x for x,y in zip(sessions, lastClickRevenue) if y != 0]
sales = [x for x,y in zip(sales, lastClickRevenue) if y != 0]
firstClickRevenue = [x for x,y in zip(sales, lastClickRevenue) if y != 0]
lastClickRevenue = [x for x in lastClickRevenue if x != 0]
```

Or you could make it a bit more [dry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by doing them all in one hit:

```
currentRevenueKeywords, sessions, sales, firstClickRevenue, lastClickRevenue = zip(*[(a,b,c,d,x) for (a,b,c,d,x) in zip(currentRevenueKeywords, sessions, sales, firstClickRevenue, lastClickRevenue) if x != 0])
```

I should mention: it looks as though you might be able to benefit from storing your data in some sort of tabular format or a dictionary, rather than a bunch of lists.

Comment: Thanks wim. These tips make a lot of sense. Will work on incorporating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the values stored in your array are actual Numerics instead of string. Try changing your code to check for Numeric 0 instead of String "0".

I would also advise looking into the filter function for only keeping values that meet a certain criteria.

```
for i in range(len(lastClickRevenue)):
    if lastClickRevenue[i] == 0:                        
        currentRevenueKeywords.pop(i)                           
        sessions.pop(i)                                         
        sales.pop(i)                                            
        lastClickRevenue.pop(i)                                 
        firstClickRevenue.pop(i)
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler. Will take that approach for a spin.